# Будет ли объект Singletone класса одним в разных сервлетах

Tags: java, servlet

Если гарантии ли что при использовании синглтона класса в разных сервлетах будет один и тот же объект?Если нет то как это можно достичь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если сделано все правильно, то в пределах одной web application будет 1 объект.

Вообще естественным синглтоном для сервлетов является объект [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) - я бы пихал свои объекты туда:

```
getServletContext().setAttribute("myObject", myObject);
```

Все равно веб контейнер гарантирует что в рамках приложения всегда будет один и только один контекст - ну а что тогда еще нужно для счастья?